# How to show this function is increasing?

Tags: calculus

Define function 
$$f(\alpha)=\frac{-(4-5\alpha-4\alpha^{2})+\sqrt{32\alpha^{3}+\alpha^{2}-40\alpha+16}}{(1-2\alpha)\alpha}=\frac{-(4-5\alpha-4\alpha^{2})+\sqrt{(4-5\alpha-4\alpha^{2})^{2}+8\alpha^2(1+\alpha)(1-2\alpha)}}{(1-2\alpha)\alpha}$$
where $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, in limiting situation, $\alpha$ can tend to $0$ or $0.5$.

I can verify that:

(1) $f(\alpha)\geq 0$ always holds when $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$

(2) Using L'Hôpital's rule to show $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=6$

I can plot this function via MATLAB and observe this function is increasing when $\alpha \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

My goal is to prove $f(\alpha)$ is increasing in $\alpha \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, the geometric graph is simple as following but the verification of increasing is not easy. How to show it?
[image]

Comment: Check the sign of the derivative.

Comment: The difficult part is just the first derivative seems to be complex and the sign is not easy to determine(I know it must be positive via simulation). Though the graph is very simple. So I want to know other tricks or some features I ignore.

Comment: Did you try $\alpha = \sin x$ and $x\in (0,\pi/6)$. I don't know if that work. Just idea.

Comment: To determine the sign of the derivative, it suffices to note the derivative is continuous and to find the zeroes of the derivative. Then you only need to check one point.

Comment: i would calculate $$f'(\alpha)$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative proof. Since your function is a bit complicated, I've chosen to do this using a function for computing [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) in Mathematica. The calculation of Gröbner bases can definitely be carried out by hand. However, this proof also relies on your ability to find roots of a single-variable polynomial. As previously noted, $f$ is continuously differentiable in $(0, 1/2)$, so we first test $f'$ at some point in $(0, 1/2)$. For example, $$f'\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 8\left(7-\frac{67}{\sqrt{105}}\right)\approx 3.69 > 0$$ Therefore, as $f'$ is continuous in $(0, 1/2)$, if $f'(x) < 0$ for any $x\in (0, 1/2)$, we must have some $x'$ between $x$ and $1/4$ where $f'(x') = 0$. Now, we are left to check for zeroes of $f'$ in $(0, 1/2)$. If we define $$s = \sqrt{32\alpha^3+\alpha^2-40\alpha+16}$$ then we have $$f'(\alpha) = \frac{-96 \alpha ^4+46 \alpha ^3+41 \alpha ^2-20 \alpha +4 \alpha  s^2-s^2+14 \alpha ^2 s-16 \alpha  s+4 s}{\alpha ^2 (2 \alpha -1)^2 s}$$ To confirm that this does, in fact, exist for all $\alpha\in (0, 1/2)$, we can find the $\alpha$ where $s = 0$ (they are approximately $-1.295$, $0.518$, and $0.746$, so we're good). Any point $(\alpha, s)$ where $f'(\alpha) = 0$ will be contained in the intersection of the zero sets of the polynomials $$s^2-(32\alpha^3+\alpha^2-40\alpha+16)$$ and $$-96 \alpha ^4+46 \alpha ^3+41 \alpha ^2-20 \alpha +4 \alpha  s^2-s^2+14 \alpha ^2 s-16 \alpha  s+4 s$$ We use an elimination order to get rid of $s$:

`GroebnerBasis[{2 (9 a^3 + 16 a^4 + a (42 - 8 s) + 2 (-4 + s) + 
      a^2 (-60 + 7 s)), -16 + 40 a - a^2 - 32 a^3 + s^2}, {a}, {s}]`

and we are then left with the output

`{-4 a^2 + 24 a^3 - 29 a^4 - 76 a^5 + 212 a^6 - 160 a^7 + 32 a^8}`

This tells us that the only $\alpha$ satisfying $f'(\alpha) = 0$ are zeroes of $$32\alpha^8-160\alpha^7+212\alpha^6-76\alpha^5-29\alpha^4+24\alpha^3-4\alpha^2 = \alpha^2(2\alpha-1)^2(8\alpha^4-32\alpha^3+19\alpha^2+8\alpha-4)$$ That last factor has a zero at $\alpha\approx 0.361$, but we can check $f'$ at this point to determine that it is not actually a zero of $f'$. No other zeroes of this polynomial fall in $(0, 1/2)$, so $f'$ must be positive everywhere in this interval, which implies that $f$ is increasing on $(0, 1/2)$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Computational approach transforms the primal problem into the root solution and verification. It is very helpful and an inspiration to me.